# How to get Game Object to move to a defined position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having issues with a function that is supposed to check whether a string is null, empty or has stuff in it, and then show/hide a UI element (by moving it on/off screen). I don't want to use `SetActive` because in future, I'm adding a slide onto/off the screen animation. It would solve the problem for now, but I would need to come back to it later.

I have checked my logic by commenting out things, and posting to the debug log, and that all seems fine, so it's definitely something wrong with how I'm using `Vector3` and `transform.position`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _narrationBar;

    private void NarrationBarShow(string NarrationTextString)
    {
        bool testString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(NarrationTextString);
        if (testString == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("String is empty or null");
            Transform gObject = _narrationBar.GetComponent<Transform>();
            if (gObject.position.y > -10f == true)
            {
                gObject.Translate(Vector3.down * _speedUIMove * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        else if (testString == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("String has stuff in it");
            Transform gObject = _narrationBar.GetComponent<Transform>();
            Vector3 defaultPos = gObject.position;
            defaultPos.y = -9.508f;
            gObject.position = defaultPos;
        }
    }
}
```

The transform adds y value to the current transform position, rather than directly setting it (so it ends up at 2 * -9.508)

Comment: What do you mean that it ends up at `2 * -9.508`?

Comment: Ok it was very late last night when I asked, so I fired it up again and yeah it doesn't end up there, it ends up at y = -15.55296. Any idea why? I don't even know where its getting that value from.

If I comment out the else if block, the object stays where it is.

Comment: Ah wait I'm still not being clear. The original object is at y = -9.508, that is important information, sorry. Although it won't always be - it could also be off screen.

Comment: @bobbypin does the object you are setting the position for have a parent transform positioned at y ~= 6 by any chance? —Inspector position values are local to the parent object, while the code you are using sets an object's world position, so an object moved by this will be listed as having a y value of -9.508 - <y value of parent>.

Comment: @Pikanchion Yes, you're right. It is nested under an empty game object which for some reason has a y value of 6.044956. I must have moved it accidentally while moving other things around. And that would explain why it's ending up with a value of ~ -15. 
I think you've solved my problem, thank you, I'll move the parent back to 0,0,0 and see if that works, but it should.
And thanks for letting me know about the inspector vs world positions, I did not know that.

Comment: It works now. I discovered a few places where the empty game objects I was using for sorting purposes had position values assigned so I went through and fixed them all, lest something like this happen again. Thanks so much for the help!
If you want to post up the solution as an answer, I can give you some rep. I don't use stackoverflow often so I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Inspector always shows `localPosition`, so if you set (using code) the `localPosition` to y=-9.508, that will work.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, thank you, I'm researching how Unity does positioning now so that I understand it a bit better. Thank you for the alternative work around though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transform.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) sets the world position of an object, meanwhile the Unity3D inspector displays an object's [local position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html).

In your case the `_narrationBar` GameObject has a parent with a *world* position of `y = 6.044956` and so the bar itself has a *local* position of `y = -15.55296` after it has been moved to a *world* position of `y = -9.508`.

This can be resolved by moving the world position of the parent object to the world origin (`y = 0`), or by assigning the intended `_narrationBar`'s local position through Transform.localPosition, depending on the intended behaviour.